# python split by character vs default

Tags: python, python-3.x

`python` library function `namedtuple` from `collections` referring [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/**init**.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py)

```
def namedtuple(typename, field_names, *, verbose=False, rename=False, module=None):

    # Validate the field names.  At the user's option, either generate an error
    # message or automatically replace the field name with a valid name.
    if isinstance(field_names, str):
        field_names = field_names.replace(',', ' ').split()
```

The last line of code above has `replace(',', ' ').split()` other than `split(',')`. I'm wondering what's the reason for it.

Here is the test code to measure the time cost:

```
from random import randrange


def create_str(n):
    a = []
    for _i in range(n):
        a.append(str(randrange(101)))

    return ','.join(a)


s = create_str(1000)

# print(s)


def test_a():
    s.split(',')


def test_b():
    s.replace(',', ' ').split()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(['test_a: ', timeit.timeit("test_a()", setup="from __main__ import test_a")])
    print(['test_b: ', timeit.timeit("test_b()", setup="from __main__ import test_b")])
```

The output from the above:

```
['test_a: ', 59.938546671997756]
['test_b: ', 68.51630863297032]
```

`s = create_str(10)` got the follows:

```
['test_a: ', 0.9246872899821028]
['test_b: ', 1.2178910280345008]
```

`s = create_str(100)` got the follows:

```
['test_a: ', 6.570624853018671]
['test_b: ', 7.8685859580291435]
```

`test_b` is faster anyway.

### Updated:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple mentioned the follows:

The field_names are a sequence of strings such as ['x', 'y']. Alternatively, field_names can be a single string with each fieldname separated by whitespace and/or commas, for example 'x y' or 'x, y'.

Comment: Compare the outputs when the input is `a, b`.

Comment: Or when the input is `'a b'`, for that matter.

Comment: It allows you to separate names with commas and whitespace and stops names with more than 1 word.

Comment: As stated in the doc of namedtuples: field_names can be a single string with each fieldname separated by whitespace and/or commas, for example 'x y' or 'x, y'

Comment: It's so it will treat definitions with commas the same as those without them (because `split()` doesn't care how much whitespace separates the items). It only has an insignificant impact the creation of namedtuples, not on their usage.

Answer (score 2):

Execution time difference aside, these two do not exactly do the same thing.

Consider a string `'a, b, c'`. Using the replace + split, it would result in `['a', 'b', 'c']` while splitting on `','` would result in `['a', ' b', ' c']`.

Asking whether the one or the other option is faster or slower is largely irrelevant since these operations (I mean using `namedtuple()`) are generally done at import time.

So unless you are generating new `namedtuple` types at runtime using dynamically generated string (not list) field names in a tight loop, the time difference is trivial.